# Kinesis triggered lambda runs below expected number of times

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda configured to be triggered by a Kinesis stream at a batch size of 100 and batch window of 60s. The Kinesis stream has about 2 shards and 2K+ total records per minute. I'd imagine this would translate into about 20+ lambda runs. However, every minutes, I'm seeing only an average of 5-6 runs.
[image]

I also see an iterationAge of 86K ms (approximately 24 Hours, my Kinesis stream holds records up to 24 hours)
[image]

The lambda function is not a fast one, runs approximately 25s on average.
[image]

I don't see any error count, or throttles or async delivery failures. [image][image]

Appreciate any advice on how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd imagine this would translate into about 20+ lambda runs

It does not work like that. If you have 2 shards, you will have **only two concurrent** lambda functions (one shard = one function), otherwise your records would be processed out of order.

> runs approximately 25s on average

That's why you have about 5-8 lambda invocations per minute:.

```
2 shards x 4 invocations for each function within 1 minute
```

You would have to increase [parallelization](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-parallelization-factor-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/) factor for your function. But this requires your records to have different partition keys within a shard. If they have same partition key, `parallelization` will not work.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, you're so right! Thank you so much for the insightful advice.